# Selenium Webdriver python headless não identifica elementos

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde, estou a programar um arquivo python utilizando selenium. Alcançei meu objetivo e o arquivo rodou direitinho. Eu fui além e decidi usar o `headless`, já no início da execução do arquivo recebo um erro:

> in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".whsOnd zHQkBf"}
> (Session info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.198)**

Indicando que ele não foi capaz de identificar o elemento na página, só que esse erro persiste também ao tentar usar o selector de `xpath`, `class`, `full xpath` e `id`.

Meu código:

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:/Users/Thunder/drivers/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://classroom.google.com/u/1/c/MTIzNzc4MTM2NjY5')
sleep(8)
logan = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
logan.send_keys('e-mail')
logan.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o option = Options() | option.headless = True?

Comment: Pode especificar melhor?

Answer (score -1):

Olá! Pra especificar melhor meu comentario vou postar o que imagino ser a resposta, pelo que vi no teu código tu não importou o chrome options, imagino que só isso resolve teu problema:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Se isso não resolver tenta colocar essa linha de código no lugar da tua 4° linha:

```
option = Options()
option.headless = True
```

Se o problema for o headless vai rodar certinho, porque pelo que entendi o código funcionou só que quando tu foi usar o headless não funcionou mais

Comment: Não funcionou amigo. DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Thunder/drivers/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)

Answer (score -3):

Opa, tenho um modelo aqui que uso nos codigos para executar tanto no modo background quanto no modo normal:

## -----------------------------------------------------

## Modo Chrome Explicito (Para ativar descomente a linha abaixo e comente o 'Modo Chrome Background')

## n = webdriver.Chrome()

## -----------------------------------------------------

## Modo Chrome Background (Para ativar descomente as linhas abaixo e comente o 'Modo Chrome Explicito')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

n = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

## -----------------------------------------------------

Veja se isso te ajuda.